# EM28XX with Android 7.1.1

Tags: android, linux, linux-device-driver, android-kernel, qualcomm

I have two devices:

1. The computer on Android 7.1.1 (Kernel 3.18);
2. The camera, with a chip EM28XX.

This camera works fine for Linux. I tested it on Ubuntu 18.04, Debian 9 and Linaro (Debian for ARM). But I can not figure out how to make it work for Android.

In Ubuntu and Debian, EM28XX support by default. You just need to specify the card number correctly and then you can get an image from it using the mplayer and xawtv. For linaro, I had to rebuild the kernel, including support for EM28XX.

If I understand correctly, then Android does not have support EM28XX by default. And I need to somehow add the necessary modules to the kernel. How to do it? How do I compile these modules?

I easily found the [sources of the modules](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git/+/android-msm-bullhead-3.10-n-preview-1/drivers/media/usb/em28xx/) I needed, but I do not understand how to get the final modules from them.

I will be glad to any help.